# How to get full name path for method call/class declaration using Roslyn

Tags: c#, analysis, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

How can I get the full qualified name of a method call with Roslyn?

For example,
 `Request.QueryString`, comes from `System.Web.UI`, how am I able to detect that?

How about class declaration within same project but different namespaces? 
As well as function call from other classes of the same project.

Appreciate any form of help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create Compilation for all `SyntaxTree` for your all project files. After it you can use symbol info for any node:

```
static string Code =
@"namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
        public int B { get; set; }

        public Test(int a, int b)
        {
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }
    }
}";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(Code);
    var syntaxTrees = new SyntaxTree[] { syntaxTree }; // Add SyntaxTree array from project files.
    var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("tempAssembly", syntaxTrees);
    var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
    var caretPosition = 46;
    var symbol = SymbolFinder.FindSymbolAtPositionAsync(semanticModel, caretPosition, new AdhocWorkspace()).Result;
    var fullName = symbol.ToString(); // fullName is "TestNamespace.Test"
}
```

Comment: thanks for this! is there a good tutorial/guide out there about symbols? the roslyn tutorial didnt help me much in understanding symbols and its usage.

Comment: how about if i invoke a function call that has multiple identifiers, for e.g. `test.ToString().ToUpper().Contains("asd")` , How can Roslyn's Symbol API / Semantic Modelling help me in analyzing this?